# Given a set of intervals, why is the average case for computing pred[i] theta(n logn)?

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, time-complexity, big-o

So I was reading my notes and I don't really get this part:

Define f, s as the starting and finishing time of an interval.
Sort all intervals by finish time.
So suppose we have a set of intervals I_1, ..., I_n and define pred[i] = the largest index j such that f_j <= s_i. (So essentially the next closest interval before i that does not overlap i).

Now we want to solve all pred[i] for all I_i in n. Why is the runtime of this theta(n log n)? I would think that, in the worst case, all of I_1, ..., I_(i-1) all overlap with I_i; and thus would take n - 1 comparisons, then n - 2 comparisons and so on. And the best case would be that none of the intervals overlap and pred(i) takes 1 comparison for each interval. I'm not sure why the runtime for "sorting and computing pred[i] values" is theta(n logn).

Answer (score 0):

The condition you named, max j such that f[j] < s[i], is not an overlap check. 
It is, rather, the last interval that starts before interval i finishes 
(they may or may not actually overlap). I suppose you can get intervals 
sorted by start times which is theta(nlogn) and  then use binary search to 
locate f[j] for every s[i] (also  theta(nlog n) )

P.S by theta I mean average case, not the worst case scenario you mentioned.

Comment: If the finish time of I_j is before the start time of I_i (ie. f[j] < s[i]) Then the entire interval of I_j is before the entire interval of I_i, is it not? Since s[j] < f[j] < s[i] < f[i].

We assume that the intervals are already sorted by finish time before calling pred.